# Variable "where" declarations in Latex

Tags: latex

In Latex, I'm attempting to do variable declarations. In other words, I am trying to do something like:

x=a+c
where a = the number of onion rings I ate.

My attempt looks like this:

```
\begin{equation}
d\phi= aE_{s}cos(\theta_{s}) +eM)cos(\alpha)A_{c}/(r^2\pi) 
\intertext{where $E_{s}$ is the sun's intensity}
\end{equation}
```

but the code doesn't compile and gives the following error: "Undefined control sequence"

The error points to the "intertext" line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "You've tried to call a command that doesn't exist. Usually this is the result of a typo. Go to the line number mentioned in the error and look at all your commands." [From here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Help#Undefined_control_sequence.) What line is giving the error?

Comment: It says missing $ inserted

Comment: on this line? `\intertext{where $E_{s}$ is the sun's intensity}` or the one above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\intertext` command works inside `align*` environment, which is not numbered ([reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)):

```
\begin{align*}
d\phi= aE_{s}\cos(\theta_{s}) +eM)\cos(\alpha)A_{c}/(r^2\pi) 
\intertext{where $E_{s}$ is the sun's intensity}
\end{align*}
```

while I'm not sure it does inside `equation`. You may also want to try:

```
\begin{equation}
d\phi= aE_s\cos(\theta_s) +eM)\cos(\alpha)A_c/(r^2\pi)\text{ %
where $E_s$ is the sun's intensity}
\end{equation}
```

that produces a different output.